# Vuex 4 не удается изменить состояние соседнего модуля

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vue3

В vuex есть 2 модуля симкарт и устройств(вместе с марками,моделями,типами).

Пример элемента массива симкарт:

```
{
id: 4,
number: 18311770045,
iccid: 601128328639574012,
operator: Билайн,
status: Первоначальная блокировка,
device: {
  imei: 469141227904895,
  model: Abcd S-2410,
  mark: Avm
 }
}
```

У устройств есть отдельная таблица моделей устройств.

Сама проблема: при редактировании названия модели устройства, я изменяю названия моделей устройства и в модуле "симкарт" в каждом элементе массива менял device.model на ту что ответил сервер.

Во Vue 2 работала запись:

```
export const update = async ({ commit, rootState, state }, form) => {
    try {
            const res = await Api.edit(form);
            let oldModel = state.models.find(x => x.id === res.data.data.id);
            commit("setUpdatedModel", res.data.data);
    
            rootState.sim.items.map(sim => {
                if (sim.device?.model && sim.device.model === oldModel.title)
                  (sim.device.model = res.data.data.title)
            });
        }
    ...
```

и меня устраивало, но решил перейти на vue 3 и vuex 4 и столкнулся с проблемой, заметил что теперь rootState.sim.items это proxy объект и rootState.sim.items.map() изменяет только первый элемент массива, а дальше просто выбрасывает в catch и вот, не знаю что делать, где искать, куда смотреть :(

Comment: Тут нужен текст ошибки и [repro] - т.к. раз первый элемент массива успешно изменяется, причина проблемы вряд ли в самой библиотеке Vuex (вероятнее что ошибки в использующем ее коде). И еще желательно пояснить тот момент, зачем вызов `map` результат которого не используется... то есть, общую логику экшна.

Comment: Сделал через commit'ы)

Answer (score 0):

Сделал через root commit.

Vue 2 давало напрямую таким образом менять данные, но в Vue 3 получается закрыли эту лазейку.

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).